# A simple global keyboard shortcut handler

Tags: linux-kernel, keyboard-shortcuts, c, system-programming

Yeah, I know there's [actkbd](https://github.com/thkala/actkbd) which allows to assign global keyboard shortcuts which will work everywhere including the text console and a graphical session but I don't want to run an extra daemon (long unmaintained as well) for a single keyboard shortcut. I want something a lot simpler with no configuration options and which has the absolute minimum amount of code.

The task is to run a command when this key combination is pressed:

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> -> `systemctl suspend`

This is probably worth posting in stackoverflow.com instead but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: 1) I'm not content with running a random daemon which could also act as a keylogger. 2) This daemon will have to be run under root or get access to `sudo` because otherwise it won't be able to run `systemctl`. A two liner for the kernel? I'm fine with that. Yes, I'm sensible.

Comment: I'd argue the contrary: your change to the kernel could as well be a two liner in userland. Opening an evdev device to listen for specific keypresses has less impact and security implications than patching in something to the sufficiently convoluted input device handling in the kernel. Your proposed "easy patch" is almost certainly more complex than you writing a daemon you can trust yourself!

Comment: Anyway [drivers/tty/sysrq.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/tty/sysrq.c?h=v5.17), modify to your heart's delight, but be aware that you need to be sure to handle things gracefully if for some reason `systemctl` can't be run with the `argp` and `argv` you provide it with.

Comment: Note that the request key gets special treatment as per security/keys/request_key.c, so unless you can actually show that you've implemented this before, you'll have to jump through extra hoops to implement listening to other keys in the kernel. I suspect the linux kernel evdev system was built so that such things specifically do not happen in kernel space, but in userland – which is for something that can very well sleep while nobody is using the keyboard and thus practically never becomes a source of overly many context switches far more desirable than putting such code in the kernel.

Comment: another thing: if you look for `kernel_exec` (or `kernel_execve`), the only way to launch an executable from kernel space AFAIK, in the kernel tree, you will not find that many occurences, simply because if possible, you'd want to leave creation of processes to userland - where existing processes have existing process state to inherit (environment, namespace view, mappings, file handlers…). /sbin/init is basically the only exception.

Comment: *you writing a daemon you can trust yourself* - that certainly looks like a ton of work.

Comment: If there were a maintained tool which is included by most distros then I'd have no qualms using it. actkbd hasn't been maintained for ages and I don't like the amount of work which needs to be done to enable it. I'd use something standard instead but as far as I can see Linux has nothing except this utility. :-( I'll leave this question open, maybe someone has other ideas.

Comment: included in your distro: your graphical session manager's key combo settings?

Comment: again, writing a userland daemon is much easier than adding this functionality to the kernel, honestly! Plus, it doesn't *belong* in the kernel, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Again, I need this to work in the console as well when no X.org session is running. I also need this to work when I haven't yet logged in so whatever features my DE has (XFCE has global keyboard shortucts) - they won't work in this case :(

Comment: I'm content with a C program which is 30 lines long at most and does one job only but I'm just not prepaired for that at the moment :-) Maybe someone who's got a similar itch could write it :-)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've edited the question to underline that I agree with your reasoning.

Comment: Sorry, a kernel patch will definitely be much longer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Linux has quite a nice framework for such things: `uinput`; evdev is a nice interface to that that doesn't hide anything. It's slim.

For basically all Linux distros there's a `python3-evdev` package (at least that's the package name on debian, ubuntu and fedora).

Then, it's a few lines of code to write your daemon; this is very much just slightly modified [example](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reading-events) code, where I added some explanations so you know what you're doing

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Copyright 2022 Marcus Müller
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
# Find the license text under https://spdx.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause.html

from evdev import InputDevice, ecodes
from subprocess import run

# /dev/input/event8 is my keyboard. you can easily figure that one
# out using `ls -lh /dev/input/by-id`
dev = InputDevice("/dev/input/event8") 

# we know that right now, "Windows Key is not pressed" 
winkey_pressed = False
# suspending once per keypress is enough
suspend_ongoing = False

# read_loop is cool: it tells Linux to put this process to rest
# and only resume it, when there's something to read, i.e. a key
# has been pressed, released
for event in dev.read_loop():

  # only care about keyboard keys
  if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:

    # check whether this is the windows key; 125 is the 
    # keyboard for the windows key
    if event.code == 125:
      # now check whether we're releasing the windows key (val=00) 
      # or pressing (1) or holding it for a while (2)
      if event.value == 0:
        winkey_pressed = False
        # clear the suspend_ongoing (if set)
        suspend_ongoing = False
      if event.value in (1, 2):
        winkey_pressed = True
    # We only check whether the end key is *held* for a while
    # (to avoid accidental suspend)
    # key code for END is 107
    elif winkey_pressed and event.code == 107 and event.value == 2:
      run(["systemctl", "suspend"])
      # disable until win key is released
      suspend_ongoing = True
```

And that's it. Your daemon in 16 lines of code.

You can directly run it with `sudo python`, but you probably want to start it automatically:

Save it as a file `/usr/local/bin/keydaemon`, `sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/keydaemon` to make it executable. Add a file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/keydaemon.unit` with contents

```
[Unit]
Description=Artem's magic suspend daemon

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/keydaemon

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With `sudo systemctl enable --now keydaemon` you can then make sure the daemon is started (instantly, and on every future boot).