# How I can remap a mouse button to a linux command or script

Tags: mouse

How I can remap a mouse button, not to a keyboard key or mouse event, but to a linux command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A simple global keyboard shortcut handler](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696526/a-simple-global-keyboard-shortcut-handler)

Comment: See my answer there. Buttons that are not left/right/middle button on a mouse are usually emulating a keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remap a mouse button to a Linux command using the xbindkeys package. Here are the steps:

Install xbindkeys package using your package manager (e.g. apt-get for Ubuntu).

Create a configuration file for xbindkeys. For example, create a file called .xbindkeysrc in your home directory and add the following line:

```
"command"
    b:button_number
```

Replace "command" with the Linux command you want to run when the button is pressed and "button_number" with the number of the mouse button you want to remap (e.g. "1" for left button, "2" for middle button, "3" for right button, etc).

Run the xbindkeys daemon to load the configuration file:

```
xbindkeys -n -v -f ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

This will start the daemon in the foreground and display debug messages.
Press the mouse button you want to remap and check if the command is executed.

Note that some mouse buttons may not be recognized by xbindkeys, depending on your mouse model and driver. In that case, you may need to use a different tool or method to remap the button.